# How to work with Timeline and generate data dynamically using map in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have followed [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-timeline/) for understanding the timeline concept and able to printing the static data but I want to print the data using `map` for that I did this logic

```
import Timeline from '@mui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineItem from '@mui/lab/TimelineItem';
import TimelineSeparator from '@mui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@mui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineDot from '@mui/lab/TimelineDot';
import TimelineOppositeContent, {
    timelineOppositeContentClasses,
} from '@mui/lab/TimelineOppositeContent';
```

Like service data:

```
const updatesList = [
    {
        Sno: 115,
        Title: "\"EXCEL\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2023-06-02",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with EXCEL. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"EXCEL\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",
    },
    {
        Sno: 114,
        Title: "\"NUVAMA\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2023-05-19",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"NUVAMA\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",
    },
    {
        Sno: 114,
        Title: "\"SHAREKHAN\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2022-05-19",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"NUVAMA\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",
    },
];
```

function logic:

```
function Updates() {

 return (

        <Container maxWidth="lg">

    <Grid container>

                <Grid item sx={12} md={12}>
                  <Timeline
                        sx={{
                            [`& .${timelineOppositeContentClasses.root}`]: {
                                flex: 0.2,
                            },
                        }}
                    >
                           {updatesList.map(list => {

                          console.log(list.Title); //data coming

                            <>(<TimelineItem>
                                <TimelineOppositeContent color='textSecondary'>
                                    {list.Sno}
                                </TimelineOppositeContent>
                                <TimelineSeparator>
                                    <TimelineDot />
                                    <TimelineConnector />
                                </TimelineSeparator>
                                <TimelineContent>{list.Sno}</TimelineContent>
                            </TimelineItem>)</>
                        })}
                    </Timeline>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default Updates;
```

How to print timeline data using map function? where I did the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried playing around with it using Stackblitz. What is the problem you encounter?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rkymnu?file=Demo.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Timeline from '@mui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineItem from '@mui/lab/TimelineItem';
import TimelineSeparator from '@mui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@mui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineDot from '@mui/lab/TimelineDot';

export default function ColorsTimeline() {

  const updatesList = [
    {
        Sno: 115,
        Title: "\"EXCEL\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2023-06-02",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with EXCEL. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"EXCEL\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",
    },
    {
        Sno: 114,
        Title: "\"NUVAMA\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2023-05-19",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"NUVAMA\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "false",
    },
    {
        Sno: 114,
        Title: "\"SHAREKHAN\" Broker Integration",
        date: "2022-05-19",
        Content: "Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the \"NUVAMA\" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.",
        Status: "true",
    },
];

  return (
    <Timeline position="alternate">
      {updatesList.map((entry) => (
          <TimelineItem>
          <TimelineSeparator>
            <TimelineDot color={JSON.parse(entry.Status) ? "success" : "secondary"} />
            <TimelineConnector />
          </TimelineSeparator>
          <TimelineContent>{entry.date}</TimelineContent>
        </TimelineItem>
      ))}
    </Timeline>
  );
}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Ok so now I tried pasting your code snippet and think the problem was that your map did not return anything.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Timeline from '@mui/lab/Timeline';
import TimelineItem from '@mui/lab/TimelineItem';
import TimelineSeparator from '@mui/lab/TimelineSeparator';
import TimelineConnector from '@mui/lab/TimelineConnector';
import TimelineContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineContent';
import TimelineDot from '@mui/lab/TimelineDot';
import TimelineOppositeContent from '@mui/lab/TimelineOppositeContent';

export default function ColorsTimeline() {
  const updatesList = [
    {
      Sno: 115,
      Title: '"EXCEL" Broker Integration',
      date: '2023-06-02',
      Content:
        'Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with EXCEL. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the "EXCEL" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.',
      Status: 'true',
    },
    {
      Sno: 114,
      Title: '"NUVAMA" Broker Integration',
      date: '2023-05-19',
      Content:
        'Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the "NUVAMA" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.',
      Status: 'false',
    },
    {
      Sno: 114,
      Title: '"SHAREKHAN" Broker Integration',
      date: '2022-05-19',
      Content:
        'Modern Algos Platform is now integrated with NUVAMA. You can directly login with your broker credentials and access all the products. Just click on “LOG IN” and under “LOGIN WITH BROKER” click on the "NUVAMA" icon and enter your login details and proceed, you will be able to access the platform.',
      Status: 'true',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <Timeline position="alternate">
      {updatesList.map((list) => (
        <TimelineItem>
          <TimelineOppositeContent color="textSecondary">
            {list.Sno}
          </TimelineOppositeContent>
          <TimelineSeparator>
            <TimelineDot />
            <TimelineConnector />
          </TimelineSeparator>
          <TimelineContent>{list.Sno}</TimelineContent>
        </TimelineItem>
      ))}
    </Timeline>
  );
}
```

[image]

Alternative solution that does not remove the `console.log` statement:

```
      {updatesList.map((list) => {
        console.log(list.Title); //data coming

        return (
          <TimelineItem>
            <TimelineOppositeContent color="textSecondary">
              {list.Sno}
            </TimelineOppositeContent>
            <TimelineSeparator>
              <TimelineDot />
              <TimelineConnector />
            </TimelineSeparator>
            <TimelineContent>{list.Sno}</TimelineContent>
          </TimelineItem>
        );
      })}
```